# How to increment the first number in a nvarchar field like this 0/0

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I can increment the number like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('0/0', 1,1) +1 AS ExtractString;
```

But I need it to return the whole number with only the first number to be incremented every time.

Comment: First, you're not incrementing anything really. You're running a select which isn't changing the underlying value. Second, this falls apart as soon as you have double digits in your first value. This sounds like an X/Y problem. Someone might provide you an answer, but this will cause you a big headache with how you have it designed at the moment.

Comment: Seems that the real issue here is that you have two values delimited in a single tuple. This violates 1NF and causes nothing but severe amounts of pain and anguish. Two values should be stored in two columns. If you truly can't fix the design then you need to look at charindex and left.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to separate the 2 parts and concatenate them back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be a little overly complicated, however, I'm taken the "pessimistic" view that there could be bad data. using a scalar value, this works:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(5) = '0/0'

SELECT CONCAT(TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(V.YourString,CI.I)) +1, STUFF(V.YourString,1,ISNULL(CI.I,0),'')) AS ExtractString
FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',V.YourString),0)-1))CI(I); --NULLIF incase of lack of /
```

And if you use a dataset:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TRY_CONVERT(int, LEFT(V.YourString, CI.I)) + 1, STUFF(V.YourString, 1, ISNULL(CI.I, 0), '')) AS ExtractString
FROM (VALUES ('1/2'),
             ('10/7'),
             ('9'),
             ('4/q'),
             ('b/12')) V (YourString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', V.YourString), 0) - 1)) CI (I); --NULLIF incase of lack of /
```

The above returns the below:

```
ExtractString
-----
11/7
9
5/q
/12
```

Note that the last value returns `'/12'` as `'b'` cannot be converted to an `int`.